# dropbox application for android

Tags: android, encryption, dropbox

i have made an application that gives user option to upload and download dropbox application. i am giving my app secret and app key. the question is when some one else use my application do they need to enter their app secret and app key?
if yes, why? and if no then whats the actual purpose of app secret and app key. i am sharing the code as well:

upload file:

```
import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.UploadRequest;
import com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxFileSizeException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxIOException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxParseException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxPartialFileException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxServerException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxUnlinkedException;

/**
 * Here we show uploading a file in a background thread, trying to show
 * typical exception handling and flow of control for an app that uploads a
 * file from Dropbox.
 */
public class UploadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {

    private DropboxAPI<?> mApi;
    private String mPath;
    private File mFile;

    private long mFileLen;
    private UploadRequest mRequest;
    private Context mContext;
    private final ProgressDialog mDialog;

    private String mErrorMsg;


    public UploadFile(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api, String dropboxPath,
            File file) {
        // We set the context this way so we don't accidentally leak activities
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        mFileLen = file.length();
        mApi = api;
        mPath = dropboxPath;
        mFile = file;

        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mDialog.setMax(100);
        mDialog.setMessage("Uploading " + file.getName());
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setProgress(0);
        mDialog.setButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // This will cancel the putFile operation
                mRequest.abort();
            }
        });
        mDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // By creating a request, we get a handle to the putFile operation,
            // so we can cancel it later if we want to
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
            String path = mPath + mFile.getName();
            mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(),
                    new ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public long progressInterval() {
                    // Update the progress bar every half-second or so
                    return 500;
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
                    publishProgress(bytes);
                }
            });

            if (mRequest != null) {
                mRequest.upload();
                return true;
            }

        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            // This session wasn't authenticated properly or user unlinked
            mErrorMsg = "This app wasn't authenticated properly.";
        } catch (DropboxFileSizeException e) {
            // File size too big to upload via the API
            mErrorMsg = "This file is too big to upload";
        } catch (DropboxPartialFileException e) {
            // We canceled the operation
            mErrorMsg = "Upload canceled";
        } catch (DropboxServerException e) {
            // Server-side exception.  These are examples of what could happen,
            // but we don't do anything special with them here.
            if (e.error == DropboxServerException._401_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                // Unauthorized, so we should unlink them.  You may want to
                // automatically log the user out in this case.
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._403_FORBIDDEN) {
                // Not allowed to access this
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._404_NOT_FOUND) {
                // path not found (or if it was the thumbnail, can't be
                // thumbnailed)
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._507_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE) {
                // user is over quota
            } else {
                // Something else
            }
            // This gets the Dropbox error, translated into the user's language
            mErrorMsg = e.body.userError;
            if (mErrorMsg == null) {
                mErrorMsg = e.body.error;
            }
        } catch (DropboxIOException e) {
            // Happens all the time, probably want to retry automatically.
            mErrorMsg = "Network error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxParseException e) {
            // Probably due to Dropbox server restarting, should retry
            mErrorMsg = "Dropbox error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            // Unknown error
            mErrorMsg = "Unknown error.  Try again.";
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
        int percent = (int)(100.0*(double)progress[0]/mFileLen + 0.5);
        mDialog.setProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        if (result) {
            showToast("File successfully uploaded");
        } else {
            showToast(mErrorMsg);
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }
}
```

Download file:

```
/**
 * Here we show getting metadata for a directory and downloading a file in a
 * background thread, trying to show typical exception handling and flow of
 * control for an app that downloads a file from Dropbox.
 */

public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {


    private Context mContext;
    private final ProgressDialog mDialog;
    private DropboxAPI<?> mApi;
    private String mPath;
    private ImageView mView;
    private Drawable mDrawable;

    private FileOutputStream mFos;

    private boolean mCanceled;
    private Long mFileLen;
    private String mErrorMsg;

    // Note that, since we use a single file name here for simplicity, you
    // won't be able to use this code for two simultaneous downloads.
    private final static String IMAGE_FILE_NAME = "dbroulette.png";
    private String localFilePath;
    private String dropboxPath;

    public DownloadFile(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api,
            String dropboxPath, String localFilePath) {
        // We set the context this way so we don't accidentally leak activities
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        this.localFilePath = localFilePath;
        this.dropboxPath= dropboxPath;

        mApi = api;
        mPath = dropboxPath;

        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mDialog.setMessage("Downloading File");
        mDialog.setButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mCanceled = true;
                mErrorMsg = "Canceled";

                // This will cancel the getThumbnail operation by closing
                // its stream
                if (mFos != null) {
                    try {
                        mFos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        mDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {           

            try{

                File localFile = new File(localFilePath);
                File fileSelected = new File(dropboxPath);

                if (!localFile.exists()) {
                    localFile.createNewFile();
                } else {
                    //copy(fileSelected, localFile);
                    //mApi.copy("/Test/test.png", "/sdcard/testfile.png");

                    BufferedInputStream br = null;
                    BufferedOutputStream bw = null;
                    DropboxInputStream fd;
                    try {
                        fd = mApi.getFileStream(fileSelected.getPath(), null);
                        br = new BufferedInputStream(fd);
                        bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                        int read;
                        while (true) {
                            read = br.read(buffer);
                            if (read <= 0) {
                                break;
                            }
                            bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        }

                    } catch (DropboxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (bw != null) {
                            try {
                                bw.close();
                                if (br != null) {
                                    br.close();
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }/*
                else {
                    showToast("File already exists");
                }*/
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                showToast("Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
catch (Exception e) {
    showToast("Exception");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
        int percent = (int)(100.0*(double)progress[0]/mFileLen + 0.5);
        mDialog.setProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        if (result) {
            // Set the image now that we have it
            //mView.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
            showToast("Successful download");
        } else {
            // Couldn't download it, so show an error
            showToast(mErrorMsg);
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }


}
```

main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Replace this with your app key and secret assigned by Dropbox.
    // Note that this is a really insecure way to do this, and you shouldn't
    // ship code which contains your key & secret in such an obvious way.
    // Obfuscation is good.
    final static private String APP_KEY = "";
    final static private String APP_SECRET = "";

    // You don't need to change these, leave them alone.
    final static private String ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    final static private String ACCESS_KEY_NAME = "ACCESS_KEY";
    final static private String ACCESS_SECRET_NAME = "ACCESS_SECRET";

    private static final boolean USE_OAUTH1 = false;

    DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mApi;
    private boolean mLoggedIn;

    private Button mSubmit;    
    private Button btnUpload;
    private Button btnDownload;

    private LinearLayout mDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // We create a new AuthSession so that we can use the Dropbox API.
        AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
        mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.auth_button);
        btnDownload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.roulette_button);
        btnUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.photo_button);
        mDisplay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.logged_in_display);

        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mLoggedIn) {
            logOut();
        } else {
            // Start the remote authentication
            if (USE_OAUTH1) {
                mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(MainActivity.this);
            } else {
                mApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MainActivity.this);
            }
        }
            }
            });

     // Upload File
        String testFile = "DeviceAdmin.apk";
        String outPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), testFile).getPath();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, outPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final File outFile = new File(outPath);
        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    UploadFile upload = new UploadFile(MainActivity.this, mApi, "/Test/", outFile);
                    upload.execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            }
        });


     // Download File
        final String localFilePath = "/sdcard/testfile.txt";
        final String dropboxPath= "/abc.txt";
        btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                DownloadFile download = new DownloadFile(MainActivity.this, mApi, dropboxPath, localFilePath);
                download.execute();
            }
        });

        setLoggedIn(mApi.getSession().isLinked());
    }

    private void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        mLoggedIn = loggedIn;
        if (loggedIn) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successful login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "logged out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    private AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
        AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair);
        loadAuth(session);
        return session;
    }

        /**
         * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a local
         * store, rather than storing user name & password, and re-authenticating each
         * time (which is not to be done, ever).
         */
        private void loadAuth(AndroidAuthSession session) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
            String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
            String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
            if (key == null || secret == null || key.length() == 0 || secret.length() == 0) return;

            if (key.equals("oauth2:")) {
                // If the key is set to "oauth2:", then we can assume the token is for OAuth 2.
                session.setOAuth2AccessToken(secret);
            } else {
                // Still support using old OAuth 1 tokens.
                session.setAccessTokenPair(new AccessTokenPair(key, secret));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            AndroidAuthSession session = mApi.getSession();

            // The next part must be inserted in the onResume() method of the
            // activity from which session.startAuthentication() was called, so
            // that Dropbox authentication completes properly.
            if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    // Mandatory call to complete the auth
                    session.finishAuthentication();
                    // Store it locally in our app for later use
                    storeAuth(session);
                    setLoggedIn(true);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Couldn't authenticate with Dropbox:" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("Exception: ", "Error authenticating", e);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a local
         * store, rather than storing user name & password, and re-authenticating each
         * time (which is not to be done, ever).
         */
        private void storeAuth(AndroidAuthSession session) {
            // Store the OAuth 2 access token, if there is one.
            String oauth2AccessToken = session.getOAuth2AccessToken();
            if (oauth2AccessToken != null) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, "oauth2:");
                edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, oauth2AccessToken);
                edit.commit();
                return;
            }
            // Store the OAuth 1 access token, if there is one.  This is only necessary if
            // you're still using OAuth 1.
            AccessTokenPair oauth1AccessToken = session.getAccessTokenPair();
            if (oauth1AccessToken != null) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, oauth1AccessToken.key);
                edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, oauth1AccessToken.secret);
                edit.commit();
                return;
            }
        }

        private void clearKeys() {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
            Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.clear();
            edit.commit();
        }

        private void logOut() {
            // Remove credentials from the session
            mApi.getSession().unlink();

            // Clear our stored keys
            clearKeys();
            // Change UI state to display logged out version
            setLoggedIn(false);
        }
}
```

this is the code for reference, please have a look and give some suggestion.my main task is to retrieve a file, encrypt and upload it on dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

No, users don't have to enter a different app key and secret. The app key and secret identifies your *app*. For example, when a user authorizes your app, they see the name of the app they're authorizing. That comes from the app key.